# The better approach - Using a database or webservice for iPad Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, ipad

I am writing an ipad application and i need to know which is better if its to use a database or use a webservice to retrieve data. Its some data with about 50-60 images and 50-60 text. Not very big. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your small amount of data I suggest you ship with the content in the app locally (database is overkill if you ask me : use flat images files and a plist). Also implement a system as part of your app that checks online for newer versions of the files, if they exist it downloads them and updates the local plist as necessary. You won't even need a web-service if you design your plist right (plist contains entries and versions for each of the images and text snippets).

Comment: Oh. Then i will do that. Does that mean that using a db is advised against if its not much data?

Comment: In my opinion, yes a database wouldn't be sensible for just 60 images and 60 text snippets. I'd have one plist containing the filenames of the images and the text snippets (and version numbers for each to check against an online plist). I also don't think you need a web-service. Others might disagree though.

Answer (score 2):

If you need offline access, or cannot predict whether the user will be online when your app is launched for the first time, use a local database.

If you can assume the user will be online when using your app, and prefer to keep the data "under your control" and up-dateable at anytime, keep your data on a server and use a web service to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides offline acces will a local database be much faster, and you won't ruin the user's data limit.